# Calculate the power, given all other numbers in an equation

Tags: exponentiation

$$100 = 200(2)^x$$

Given all numbers in the equation, how do I find $x$?

Comment: is it $$100=200\cdot 2^x$$?

Comment: yes. I couldn't figure out the formatting, so I included a link to the image of my euqation

Comment: Divide each side by $200$. This will make $x$ a bit more isolated, which is almost always a good thing. Reduce the fraction you get on the left-hand side. What do you get then?

Comment: .5 = 2 ^ x (where ^ = power of)

Comment: Try to factorise both left hand side and right hand side then compare the powers with same base.

Comment: @HaloMediaz: Arthur's advice was not to _carry out_ the division in decimal (which would produce 0.5), but merely to _reduce the fraction_, giving $\frac12$. So you get $\frac12=2^x$. Does that remind you of anything?

Comment: @HenningMakholm thx man. that makes alot of sense

Comment: @HenningMakholm I can't take the square root of x to both sides get rid of the x, which is my problem.

Comment: @HaloMediaz: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for a tutorial in formatting formulas. `$100=200 \cdot 2^x$` produces $100=200\cdot2^x$ and `$.5=2^x$` produces $.5=2^x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you divide both sides by 200 you end up with
$$ \frac12 = 2^x $$
At this point you have to *remember* that $\frac12$ is exactly how $2^{-1}$ is *defined*, such that $x=-1$ is a solution.

Comment: ok. I got it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Take the logarithm on both sides and use $log(a^n)=n\ log(a)$ and $log(ab)=log(a)+log(b)$

Comment: If you divide by $200$ first, you do not need the second equation.

Comment: But he'll need to evaluate $\log_2\frac12$, that is, to solve the equation $\frac12=2^y$ for $y$, which is exactly the problem he's trying to solve in the first place!

Comment: My hint leads him to $log(\frac{1}{2})=y\ log(2)$. The rest should be easy. It does not even matter, if he uses $log_{10}$ or ln, unless he uses two DIFFERENT logarithms.

Answer (score 0):

cancalling with $100$ we get $$2^{-1}=2^x$$ thus we get $$x=-1$$

Comment: how did you get -1?

Answer (score 0):

Notice, we have $$100=200\cdot 2^x$$ 
Diving both the sides by $100$ we get $$\frac{100}{100}=\frac{200}{100}\cdot 2^x$$

$$1=2\cdot2^x$$ $$1=2^{x+1}$$
 $$2^0=2^{x+1}$$ Comparing powers on both the sides, we get $$x+1=0\iff x=-1$$